# Why was Joshua allowed to break Shabbat in attacking Yericho?

Tags: shabbat, halacha-theory, army-military-war, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot, joshua--book-of

In [Joshua 6](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0606.htm) the Jews marched around Jericho, thereby attacking it.

- Why was Joshua allowed to break the Shabbat e.g carrying their weapons in a public domain when attacking Yericho?
- Surely this march around Yericho began on Rosh Chodesh and lasted for 7 consecutive days- how was this allowed on Shabbat?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Chaim22! Thanks for your interesting question. I've edited it to (a) give background info on the battle (with a link to Joshua) for those who need it and (b) make the post actually contain your question. You can [edit] it further to clarify why you think there's a problem with Joshua's actions. For example, have you heard that it's forbidden to wage war on _Shabas_? that it's forbidden to break a wall on _Shabas_? or what? I hope you stick around the site and enjoy it. You may particularly like our 32 preexisting questions on [tag:Sefer-Yehoshua].

Comment: Today Rabbah haver, shalom !

Comment: Does war not override Shabbos in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yehoshua was a prophet

[Mishneh Torah» Sefer Madda » Yesodei haTorah - Chapter Ten](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/904996/jewish/Yesodei-haTorah-Chapter-Ten.htm)

[Halacha 5](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Foundations_of_the_Torah.10.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> When a prophet proclaims that another individual is [also] a prophet, we accept the latter as a prophet without requiring [any further] investigation. Thus, after **Moses, our teacher, proclaimed that Joshua [was a prophet]**, all the Jews believed in him before he performed any wonders. The same holds true for subsequent generations. ...

and

[Mishneh Torah» Sefer Madda » Yesodei haTorah - Chapter Nine](http://m.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/904993/jewish/Yesodei-haTorah-Chapter-Nine.htm)

[Halacha 3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Foundations_of_the_Torah.9.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> ...
>
> **When a prophet - who has already proven himself to be a prophet - instructs us to violate one of the mitzvot of the Torah or many mitzvot, whether they be of a severe or light nature, for a limited amount of time, it is a mitzvah to listen to him**.
>
> The Sages of the early generation taught as part of the oral tradition: **If a prophet tells you to violate the precepts of the Torah** as Elijah did on Mount Carmel, listen to him with regard to all things except the worship of false gods. **This applies when his command is temporary in nature**.
>
> ...
>
> If they would have asked Elijah: How can we violate the Torah's command [Deuteronomy 12:13]: "[Be careful...] lest you offer your burnt offerings everywhere"?, he would have told them: We should not say anything, but anyone who offers a sacrifice outside [the Temple premises] is liable for **karet**, as Moses said. [The present instance,] however, [is an exception]. I am offering a sacrifice today outside [the Temple] at God's command in order to disprove the prophets of Ba'al.
>
> **Similarly, if any [other] prophet commands us to transgress for a limited time, it is a mitzvah to listen to him**. If, however, he says that the mitzvah has been nullified forever, he is liable for execution by strangulation, for the Torah has told us: "[It is] for us and our children forever."

Comment: As an aside, I'm not sure that this answer is correct, although not due to the lack of source for Yehoshua's prophet-hood. I believe that many times, war overrules the Shabbos, so there is no need to rely on a 'special circumstance' ruling by a prophet. This isn't a matter of a prophets' ability to permit a prohibition, but rather on the ability of war to overrule Shabbos.

Comment: Todah Rabbah friend for your answer, I am compiling these answers to hopefully give some insight/Midrash on this subject to our Facebook community.

Comment: @Chaim22 no problem, you can thank me by giving an arrow up (by my answer) and maybe even a check mark

Comment: @hazoriz Eyn Devar, shalom.

Answer (score 4):

Rashi indeed says that the 7th day of encircling Yericho was on Shabbos.

[Rashi on Yehoshua 6:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Joshua.6.15?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Joshua.6.15.1&lang2=bi):

> "ביום השביעי" - שבת היה

This siege was permitted on Shabbos for the Sake of *Milchemes Mitzva* (Conquering Eretz Yisroel in the time of Yehshua) as the *pasuk* says "Until the city Falls"([Devarim 20:20](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.20.20?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) which means as long as it takes to subjugate the City including on Shabbos, as long as the war started before Wednesday.

Rambam [Hilchos Melachim 6:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Kings_and_Wars.6.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes:

> צרין על עיירות של עכו"ם שלשה ימים קודם השבת ועושין עמהם מלחמה בכל יום ויום ואפילו בשבת. שנאמר עד רדתה ואפילו בשבת בין מלחמת מצוה בין מלחמת רשות
>
> We may besiege a non-Jewish city (even) on Shabbos and we may make war with them even on Shabbos, as it says, “until it falls” ([Deut. 20:20](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.20.20?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi)). We do battle on Shabbos whether it is a War of Mitzvoh or a Discretionary War.