# Hakafot of Jericho on Shabbat?

Tags: joshua--book-of, yehoshua-joshua

If the siege of Jericho lasted 7 days were hakafot done on Shabbat? If so was there any issue with hakafot and any other war-making occurring on Shabbat? Is one not required to desist from non-essential warfare on Shabbat?

The hakafot began on the 22nd of Nissan, which day of the week?

Comment: Conquering Israel *is* considered a milchemet mitzvah (commanded war), and therefore essential.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/62237/why-was-joshua-allowed-to-break-shabbat-in-attacking-yericho